# Does column of integers contains value

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

What is the fastest regarding performance way to check that integer column contains specific value?

I have a table with 10 million rows in postgresql 8.4. I need to do at least 10000 checks per sec. 
Currently i am doing query `SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = my_value` and then checking does `DataReader` have rows. But it is quite slow. Is there any way to speed up without loading whole column into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select `COUNT` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = my_value
```

It will return just one integer value - number of rows matching your select condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things,

As Marcin pointed out, you want to use the `COUNT(*)` if all you need is to know how many. You also need an index on that column. The index will have the answer pretty much right at hand. Without the index, Postgresql would still have to go through the entire table to count that one number.

```
CREATE INDEX id_idx ON table (id) ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Something of the sort should get you there. Whether it is enough to run the query 10,000/sec. will depend on your hardware...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `where id = X` then all values matching `X` will be returned. Suppose `1000` values match `X` then `1000` values will be returned.

Now, if you only want to check if the value is at least once then after you matched the first value there is no need to process the other `999`. Even if you count the values you are still going through all of them.

What I would do in this case is this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table
WHERE id = my_value
LIMIT 1
```

Note that I'm not even returning the `id` itself. So if you get one record then the value is there.

Of course, in order to improve this query, make sure you have an index on the `id` column.